# How to align the position of figure and table in Longtable environment

Tags: longtable

I have the following code

```
 \begin{landscape}
    \fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont
    \newgeometry{total={7in,7in}, bottom=7cm}
    \begin{longtable}[htbp]{l*{6}{l}}
    \caption{\large{Regression model conditional on the position of investors}}}\\ \multicolumn{7}{@{}p{0.9\linewidth}@{}}{This table reports the regression result for fixed-effect regression conditional on the \sym{*}\sym{*}\sym{*},\sym{*}\sym{*},\sym{*} indicates the coefficients are statistically significant at 99\%, 95\% and 90\% respectively.\addlinespace}\\
    \toprule
    &\multicolumn{1}{l}{NPV}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{NPV}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{NPV}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{NPV}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{NPV}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{NPV}\\
     &\multicolumn{1}{l}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{(6)}\\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \caption{\textbf{\large{Regression model conditional on the position of investors}- Continued}}\\
    \toprule
    \midrule
     \endhead

        \multicolumn{7}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape       
                            Continue on the next page}
    \endfoot
        \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
   &&&&&&\\
    \end{longtable}
    \end{landscape}
```

However, because I am using the command,

```
\multicolumn{7}{@{}p{0.9\linewidth}@{}}
```

The title of the table is not aligned with the table and caption, this problem has bothered me for a LONG time, I really wish some of you can help me out.
For instance, what I want is
[image]
But what I am having is 
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: As always on this site: you are much much more likely to get help if you provide a full (but minimal) self contained example instead of a sniplet like this.

Comment: Unrelated: `\large` and friends does not take any arguments and in general you should not be inserting text formatting (like size) into `\caption`

Comment: The table caption is be default centred, whereas paragraphs indentation start a fixed width from the page margin, so the two shouldn't expect to be aligned in general. Perhaps one solution is to have non-centred captions.

Comment: @oliversm Then probably, a simplified way to ask what I want is, how to move the position of title in longtable environment

Comment: (i) please extend your code fragment to complete, compilable small document with your table (ii) remove all errors in table code, (iii) add at least one row of the table body.